# "make check" fails when installing HDF5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, hdf5

I downloaded hdf5-1.8.15-patch1.tar.bz2, and tried to install it on my Ubuntu, with this command:

```
    CC=mpicc ./configure --enable-parallel --enable-shared
    make
    make check
```

yet during make check, I got this error:

```
***** 1 FAILURE! *****
Command exited with non-zero status 1
0.78user 0.08system 0:00.86elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 10216maxresident)k
0inputs+1224outputs (0major+51752minor)pagefaults 0swaps
make[4]: *** [dt_arith.chkexe_] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/tools/hdf5-1.8.15-patch1/test'
make[3]: *** [build-check-s] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/tools/hdf5-1.8.15-patch1/test'
make[2]: *** [test] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/tools/hdf5-1.8.15-patch1/test'
make[1]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/tools/hdf5-1.8.15-patch1/test'
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

this is my 'uname -a' and 'gcc -v':

```
    uname -a
    Linux ip-172-31-23-30 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    gcc -v
    gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
```

Comment: Are there any errors from `./configure` or `make`?

Comment: Hi daniel, I did a grep for "fatal error" in config.log, and got these:  g++: fatal error: no input files
g++: fatal error: no input files
conftest.cpp:11:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
conftest.cpp:11:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c:12:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c:12:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c:73:28: fatal error: mach/mach_time.h: No such file or directory
...

Answer (score 0):

It seems worth trying with lower optimizations flags (-O1 or -O0) following previous issues:
https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/known_problems/previssues.html